# How to program FragmentB inside FragmentA?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm making an application as a school project and I'm having trouble in programming a certain FragmentB inside FragmentA. Trouble, more so, I don't know how to even if I had an extensive search done.

`FragmentA` to `MainActivity` works properly (or so, because doesn't give out any errors). I used SwitchCase in the `MainActivity.java` and it works.

MainActivity.java

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.navigation);

        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
                (new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                        Fragment selectedFragment = null;
                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.navigation_home:
                                selectedFragment = HomeScreenFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.navigation_profile:
                                selectedFragment = ProfileScreenFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                            case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                                selectedFragment = NotifScreenFragment.newInstance();
                                break;
                        }
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, selectedFragment);
                        transaction.commit();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, HomeScreenFragment.newInstance());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

ProfileScreenFragment.java (this is what I want to have a FragmentB)

```
public class ProfileScreenFragment extends Fragment {
    public static ProfileScreenFragment newInstance() {
        ProfileScreenFragment fragment = new ProfileScreenFragment ();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_screen2, container, false);
    }
}
```

fragment_profile_screen2.xml (the frame_layout is where I want to put the `FragmentB`)

```
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="7dp"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_mdpi" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="313dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="Profile"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="25sp" />

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    app:srcCompat="@drawable/icon_more2" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white">

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/profile_profile"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Profile" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/profile_posts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Posts" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/profile_uploads"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Uploads" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
                android:id="@+id/profile_likes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Likes" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

How or what code should I be writing for `FragmentB` be put inside the `ProfileScreenFragment.java`?

Is it also possible to use SwitchCase in `ProfileScreenFragment.java` for the Tabs?

Thank you so much. If ever there are clarifications needed in the codes I used, please don't hesitate to ask. I'm still learning the basics of it all so I'm 50/50 on the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Add this snippet in ProfileScreenFragment.

```
@Override
protected void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.frame_layout, FragmentB.newInstance());
    transaction.commit();
}
```

For the tab layout, you can add a tab change listener

```
TabLayout tabLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        switch (tab.getPosition()) {
            case 0: // Handle 1st tab item
                break;
            case 1: // Handle 2nd tab item
                break;
            case 2: // Handle 3rd tab item
                break;
            case 3: // Handle 4th tab item
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked. Follow-up question if I may.

My fragment_profile_screen2.xml has an AppBar>Toolbar>TabsItem(4 items). Would I be able to use SwitchCase to it like what I've done with MainActivity.java? Because using SwitchCases looks easier. Thank you

Comment: Nice. Appreciate if you vote this answer when it works. :) Yes you can. Individual fragment has it's own view therefore you can call view.findByViewId to it.

Comment: I'm sorry but can you expound on that? :( I want to put the SwitchCase in ProfileScreenFragment.java because fragment_profile_screen2.xml is connected to it. How should I start it? Toolbar? TabLayout? Because how it started in MainActivity.java

Comment: Why do you want to do that? What operation would you like to do in the "subfragment" that you need in it profile screen?

Comment: The MainActivity has BottomNavigationView only and I used Fragments for the NavigationItems so that when the user taps the (ex:) Profile in the NavigationView, the fragment_profile_screen2.xml and ProfileScreenFragment gets called out. I thought it would be the same with when a Fragment calls out another Fragment, or am I wrong? I'm sorry if it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: i see. check the modified answer above.

Comment: This is embarrassing to ask, but what am I going to put inside the cases? How am I going to call out the java classes? and how about in the onTab(Un/Re)selected? :(

Comment: You only can only use the callback methods when necessary depending on your usage. Your question about how do you call java classes is unclear.

Comment: Ah, what I meant was: since MainActivity used selectedFragment = ProfileScreenFragment.newInstance();, what should I use? I've typed in what you've suggested but I'm unable to conjure up a way how to use it properly.